# Login in Facebook SDK for Unity3d in android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I need help using Facebook SDK for Unity3d in android. I was trying to do all the tutorial said, but I can't login succesfully. I do FB.Init and its ok, but FB.Login never works. Always return this:

```
{
   "is_logged_in":false,
   "user_id":"",
   "access_token:"",
   "access_token_expires_at":"01/01/0001 00:00:00"
}
```

please, i need fix it as soon as possible.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Share some code please. It hard to guess your problem.

Comment: void Awake()
    {
        FB.Init(SetInit, OnHideUnity);
        
    }

public void OnClickTest()
    {

        FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
    }

void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        m_Debug.text += " - LoginCallback - " + result.Text + "\n";

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            OnLoggedIn();
        }
    }

Comment: My project:
https://mega.co.nz/#!SEZgBTRK!ToitotstsF21kgD7ZKPbwDiX47DBHffTZfmKI4Jv59A

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem this fixed it for me i was using the wrong keyhash in facebook, maybe you have the same problem

open the AndroidFacebook script and scroll till you see this:

```
 public void OnLoginComplete(string message)
        {
            var parameters = (Dictionary<string, object>)MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(message);

            if (parameters.ContainsKey("user_id"))
            {
                isLoggedIn = true;
                userId = (string)parameters["user_id"];
                accessToken = (string)parameters["access_token"];
                accessTokenExpiresAt = FromTimestamp(int.Parse((string)parameters["expiration_timestamp"]));
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey("key_hash"))
            {
                keyHash = (string)parameters["key_hash"];
                print (keyHash);
            }

            OnAuthResponse(new FBResult(message));
        }
```

as you can see inside where it pertains to keyhash i put

```
print (keyHash);
```

so now if you run it and log in and use logcat on eclipse or a logger to see the print() that come out of the code check the keyhash you have in your facebook app and the one that is printed out with print (keyHash); witch is the correct one, hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't test it, but probably was the keyHash. I changed the OpenSSL that i had installed and then works fine.

Works with this OpenSSL: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm